# Athena SQL create table from variable number of tables

Tags: mysql, sql, parquet, amazon-athena

I want to create a table / view from variable multiple table names that I get from a SELECT query.
It's possible to create a table from multiple known tables like so:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT column_1, column_2
FROM clients_1, clients_2, ... clients_n;
```

To get list of tables I can use something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name like '%clients_%';
```

Which returns:

```
     table_name
1    clients_1
2    clients_2
```

How can I use the table names result as a list in CREATE TABLE FROM clause?

I tried something like this with a WITH:

```
WITH mytable AS 
  (SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name like '%clients_%')
    CREATE TABLE new_table AS
    SELECT column_1, column_2
    FROM mytable;
```

But it's mostly not working.
And even if it does, for example by not using WITH and selecting * columns -

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE
table_name like '%clients_%');
```

new_table is just a copy of mytable/nested query.

Ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: You say "it's mostly not working". What _is_ working and what _is not_ working? Typically with SQL systems, DDL commands (like `CREATE TABLE`) do not permit the inclusion of a `SELECT` command within the DDL command, so I'd be surprised if you got _any_ of it working. Worst case, you'll need to do a query for table names and then programmatically combine them into a `CREATE VIEW` command that is sent separately.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the last example I gave works, with SELECT * on results of FROM (SELECT). But the resulting table is just the output of the nested select in the FROM section (a table of table names, not the actual columns within each discovered table).
I think you're right and splitting this into two queries / commands will be much simpler.

Comment: Yes, I can see that the last example would select from the _output_ of the nested query, rather than using the "name" of the table from the nested query. This type of thing could work within Amazon Redshift as a Stored Procedure that "builds" the Select statement, but it wouldn't be so simple in Athena.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with a VIEW like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW clients_all AS
  SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM client1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM client2
```

The downside is I'll have to update the view whenever adding new client_n table,
And explicitly specify the name of the tables rather than inferring them from a query,
But I probably had to break it into two queries anyway even if creating a table as originally intended.